# How to amplify regions with specific color in an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want to amplify regions with a specified color in an image. For this purpose I have defined a simple function

$B(x,y)=s_r(x,y) \cdot w_r + s_g(x,y) \cdot w_g + s_b(x,y) \cdot w_b$

which produces a gray scale image B(x,y).

The weights I have defined with

$w_r \in [-2,2],w_g \in [-2,2], w_b \in [-2,2]$

The channels of the images are the functions $s_x$ for each channel.
I use the result of this amplification for a color thresholding. For example for yellow I have manually defined
$w_r=1$, $w_g=1$ and $w_b = -2$.
My Problem now is, to get "good" values for the weights automatically. First I thought taking the maximal values of histograms would be a good way, but the results are not satisfactorily.

How can I automatically determine the weights for the amplification?

How would you deal with white and black?

Or is there a better way to amplify the regions with a specific color?

Comment: Why don't try working in HSB ... seems much easier

Comment: Do you want to amplify regions matching *exactly* a color or do you want to make a more or less smooth amplification include colors close to your chosen one?

Comment: The second, I want to amplify a color range.

Comment: @martin, I would like to attenuate regions matching exactly a "True" RGB color where I know the bounding box x and y coordinates. How might I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you are doing a binary classification with the desired color region set as 1 after applying your algorithm.
Then you can provide a set of color images (histograms) and desired outputs. The weights can be posed as the unknown quantities for this set of linear equations. Lo you have a overdetermined system & you can apply any method like [Moore-penrose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Moore-PenroseMatrixInverse.html) inversion to estimate the weights.